# Weird groovy classloading exception

Tags: groovy, classloader

we want to use groovy/grails as a Glassfish-Remote-Client, but we are running into weird ClassLoading Problems.

First the Testcode, which triggers the Errors, when called via groovy/grails. 
 It's fine, when it is invoked via java.
 When running via groovy, it triggers a 
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject cannot be cast to javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectDelegate
 in (PortableRemoteObject.java:77)
 Before that error, it's possible to make that cast manually.

========== source ==========

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class J2EETest {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new J2EETest().classLoaderTest();
   }

   public static void classLoaderTest() throws Exception {
           ClassLoader classLoader = J2EETest.class.getClassLoader();
           ClassLoader threadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
           System.out.println("classLoader: " + classLoader);
           System.out.println("threadClassLoader: " + threadClassLoader);

           Class klass = Class.forName( "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject", false, threadClassLoader );
           Object obj = klass.newInstance();
           System.out.println("Object -> " + obj.toString());
           // This works
           javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectDelegate del = (javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectDelegate) obj;
             try {
                 System.out.println("Init of javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject");
                   // This doesn't work ! 
                   System.out.println( Class.forName("javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject", true, threadClassLoader));
                   Class prOklass = javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.class;
                   Field staticfield = prOklass.getDeclaredField("proDelegate");
                   staticfield.setAccessible(true);
                   System.out.println("Reflection: PortableRemoteObject.proDelegate ->" + staticfield.get(null));
                   System.out.println("OK");
               }
               catch(Throwable e) {
                   System.err.println("BOOM");
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }

  }

  }
```

======= JAVA Test RUN =======

```
$ export CLASSPATH=build:lib/glassfish/gf-client-module.jar     # gf-client-module.jar -> GLASSFISH-Client Libs
$ java  -Djavax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject test.J2EETest 
classLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@e776f7
threadClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@e776f7
Object -> com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject@5511e28
Init of javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject class javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject
Reflection: PortableRemoteObject.proDelegate -> com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject@20e5f01b

OK
```

======= now the Groovy-Version =======

```
$ groovy -Djavax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject -e "test.J2EETest.classLoaderTest()"
classLoader: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader@5dcba031
threadClassLoader: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader@5dcba031
Object -> com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject@1bf3f158
Init of javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject

BOOM

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at test.J2EETest.classLoaderTest(J2EETest.java:83)
at test.J2EETest$classLoaderTest.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at script_from_command_line.run(script_from_command_line:1)

at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:266)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:517)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:172)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:553)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:337)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:323)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:120)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:100)     

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:130)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject cannot be cast to   javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectDelegate   at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.<clinit>(PortableRemoteObject.java:77)
 ... 22 more
```

======= now the Groovy-Version WITHOUT -Djavax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass =======

This works, but is not an option for a glassfish-client, because InitialContext (or something else there) will set javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject

```
$ groovy -e "test.J2EETest.classLoaderTest()"                       
classLoader: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader@3b4d82e1
threadClassLoader: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader@3b4d82e1
Object -> com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject@527e2f47
Init of javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject
class javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject
Reflection:  PortableRemoteObject.proDelegate -> com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject@5b3bd1c0  # com.sun.corba.ee != com.sun.corba.se
```

OK

Has anybody had a similar issue or knows how to get this code working ?

Kind regards

Frank

Comment: Isn't this the same question as [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619853/ejb-lookup-to-glassfish-server-from-groovy)?

Comment: Yes, but in a more simplified way (no direct dependencies to glassfish anymore). I guess the former topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your example and I get:

```
classLoader: groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@538d7ace
threadClassLoader: groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@1e22ab57
Caught: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject
    at java_lang_Class$forName.call(Unknown Source)
    at test.J2EETest.classLoaderTest(J2EETest.groovy:16)
    at test.J2EETest$classLoaderTest.call(Unknown Source)
    at test.J2EETest.main(J2EETest.groovy:7)
```

The best I could suggest is to isolate the things that vary. The most likely culprit is the JVM you usse in both cases. Compare the JVM you use for executing groovy to the JVM you use for running the jar directly. I would also suggest dropping groovy-all.jar into the Classpath and try running the Groovy interpreter from Java.